# How to automatically create a string with 1s in Java

Tags: java

I am wondering if there is a shorter way in Java to create a String with a number of 1s. I would like to create a string like 111, or 1111 or 11111 without using loops or recursive calls.

For example, in Perl code, something like '0b' . ('1' x $numberOf1s) would return 11 (if numberOf1s) is 2 and 111 (if numberOf1s) is 3

Thanks

Comment: You may want to provide more detail about what you are trying to achieve and what you've tried already since String ones = "1111"; is a pretty short way of creating a string of 1s.

Comment: `String ones = "1111";` how about this? from your explanation this is the best one can suggest

Comment: _How do I create a repeating construct without loops or recursion?_ You don't. Anything to do this is going to loop in some fashion.

Comment: "I am wondering if there is a shorter way in Java to create a String with a number of 1s" shorter than what?

Comment: For example, in Perl code, something like '0b' . ('1' x $numberOf1s) would return 11 (if numberOf1s) is 2 and 111 (if numberOf1s) is 3

Comment: you can use StringUtils class method provided by Apache Commons

Answer (score 3):

`StringUtils` provided by *Apache commons jar* has many static methods which can be used.For example,`StringUtils` has a method `repeat(String str,int repeat)`.Example

```
String str = StringUtils.repeat("1",5);
```

See the doc here [StringUtils's repeat method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat(java.lang.String,%20int))

Answer (score 2):

If you have a maximum number of 1s that you would want to generate, you can do this:

```
private static final String ALL_ONES = "11111111111111111111111111"; // max # of 1s

public String getNOnes(int n) {
    // perhaps should do some error checking here
    return ALL_ONES.substring(0, n);
}
```

If you have no maximum in mind, you could use [@f1sh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26004340/535871):

```
public String getNOnes(int n) {
    char [] ones = new char[n];
    Arrays.fill(ones, '1');
    return new String(ones);
}
```

But the entire problem seems to have ridiculous requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In short: no.

You can use something like `Arrays.fill(char[] arr, char value)` to fill up a whole char array and then make a String out of it, but internally it uses a `for` loop anyways.

Also: what requirement would disallow a `for` loop?

Comment: where user has specified that he wants to use char array or how he want to create string? what is the input? what is his requirement?

Comment: @VD' - I think you misunderstood this answer. f1sh is suggesting to use a `char[]` as a temporary variable to create a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like

```
new String(new char[5]).replace('\0','1')
```

but `replace` iterates over all characters in `char[]` which are by default set to `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

(Any power of two) - 1 converted to binary is a string of all 1s.
For Example

```
4-1 = 3 = binary 11
8-1 = 7 = binary 111
16-1= 15 = binary 1111 and so on.
```

I used this fact to write the following code...
BigInteger will produce any size of string but will be a bit slow. If you need a string of size below 64 you can use long in the same logic.

```
private static String stringOf1s(int size)
{
   BigInteger powerOfTwo =  BigInteger.TWO.pow(size);
   return powerOfTwo.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).toString(2);
}

private static String stringOfOnes(int size)
{
    long powerOfTwo = (long) Math.pow(2,size);

    return Long.toBinaryString(powerOfTwo-1);
}
```